What is the wiring of 1 plug (.206" or coded PJ-068) aviation headset?
Boeing aircrafts have been using 1 jack headset on commercial airliners in the past. The plug is same as a microphone plug of modern GA dual plugs. Does anyone know how to wire a PJ-068 plug for both microphone and audio?



From what I've gathered, Plantronics MS200 and Telex 5x5 PRO have been using single plug, and looks like single plug PJ-068 connectors still work on modern Boeing two-plug audio panels.
